# adding a frame, error during compiling

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28C%2B%2B%29) link, tf2/tutorials/adding a frame(c++), but after i put the frame_broadcaster.cpp file and compile it using `catkin_make` im getting this error:

```
Building CXX object learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/frame_tf2_broadcaster.dir/src/frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp.o
/home/dinesh/tf/src/learning_tf2/src/frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/dinesh/tf/src/learning_tf2/src/frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp:17:6: error: ‘tf2’ has not been declared
      tf2::Quaternion q;
          ^
    /home/dinesh/tf/src/learning_tf2/src/frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp:17:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘q’
          tf2::Quaternion q;
                          ^
    /home/dinesh/tf/src/learning_tf2/src/frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp:18:12: error: ‘q’ was not declared in this scope
                q.setRPY(0, 0, 0);
                ^
    make[2]: *** [learning_tf2/CMake

Files/frame_tf2_broadcaster.dir/src/frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/frame_tf2_broadcaster.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I'm using ROS indigo 64 bit cpu.

This is the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(learning_tf2)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  tf2
  tf2_ros
  turtlesim
)



catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


add_executable(turtle_tf2_broadcaster src/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp)
target_link_libraries(turtle_tf2_broadcaster
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(turtle_tf2_listener src/turtle_tf2_listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(turtle_tf2_listener
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(frame_tf2_broadcaster src/frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp)
target_link_libraries(frame_tf2_broadcaster
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

and this is frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp file:

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
      ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf2_broadcaster");
      ros::NodeHandle node;
    
       tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
      geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;
   
     transformStamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
     transformStamped.header.frame_id = "turtle1";
     transformStamped.child_frame_id = "carrot1";
     transformStamped.transform.translation.x = 0.0;
     transformStamped.transform.translation.y = 2.0;
     transformStamped.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
     tf2::Quaternion q;
           q.setRPY(0, 0, 0);
     transformStamped.transform.rotation.x = q.x();
     transformStamped.transform.rotation.y = q.y();
     transformStamped.transform.rotation.z = q.z();
     transformStamped.transform.rotation.w = q.w();
   
     ros::Rate rate(10.0);
     while (node.ok()){
       tfb.sendTransform(transformStamped);
       rate.sleep();
       printf("sending\n");
     }
   
   };
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238969/adding-a-frame,-error-during-compiling/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-07-07**:
Looks like it's a syntax error or a dependency issue. Can you please share the `frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp` and your CMake file? The issue will be in one of those files

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-07-07**:
I wanted to use tree frame to show point cloud in rviz and than show some markers in the same frame to visualize how the codes are analizing the points, i can do that with tf right?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-07-07**:
ok, i hot the error, i have to change the name of ros node `my_tf2_broadcaster to` frame_tf2_broadcaster, before this also the tutorial says the launch file is in bin folder, but i found it inside lib. ok error solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

change my_tf2_broadcaster to frame_tf2_broadcaster.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0